Formatting hovertext in vscode in repo with both ts & proptypes
I have a repo using both typescript and proptypes (it started with proptypes and we only recently added ts so I don't want to remove proptypes as the runtime checking is useful), and the hover text on components shows the typescript type and then the proptypes, which is a bit redundant.
screenshot
I was wondering if

there is a way to have only one or the other, preferably typescript.
there is a way to add comments to individual params.

I have no idea about potentially removing either proptypes or typescript, but as for the individual comments, I've tried adding JSDoc /** comment */ before individual props in both the typescript type (I also tried interface) and the proptypes,
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  /**  comment */
  customTestId?: string;
}

but they don't show up. I can't even get a comment above Props to show up on the hover text. I've only been able to get a component comment to show up using the below, but the text shows up at the bottom of the hovertext and the params/props don't show up in any detail.
/**
 * Common_InputField is a wrapper component for input fields that includes:
 * - Label with optional icon and tooltip.
 * - Error handling display.
 * - Loading state.
 * @param {Props}
 * @type {React.FC<Props>}
 * @returns {React.ReactElement}
 */

I know I could probably get it to show up with JSDocs if I did the params individually, but I don't want to have to make and maintain a THIRD set of props just for JSDocs.
Ideally I'd like to hover over a component and have the hover text show

Component description first
Then component type with props, including any comments on individual params

